# relation between pushforward and pullback

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

I think its true that for an isomorphism $f: X\rightarrow Y$ of schemes there is an equivalence $\mathbf{Coh}(X) \leftrightarrow \mathbf{Coh}(Y)$ induced by $f_*$ and $f^*$. I'd be interested in how someone thinks intuitively about this and if that implies that $f^*=f^{-1}_*$? This seems to follow from this, but I've rarely seen it anywhere so far.

Answer (score 1):

First, you are talking about categories, so instead of bijection you should talk about equivalence. Second, you don't have either of these in general; for instance if $X = \mathbb{P}^1$ and $Y$ is a point,
$$
f_*(\mathcal{O}(-1)) = 0.
$$

Comment: But I said $f$ is an isomorphism?

Comment: I'm basically asking about auto-equivalences of $\mathbf{Coh}(X)=\mathbf{Coh}(Y)$, I don't know why you came up with this example of a line and a point.

Comment: Right, I missed that $f$ is assumed to be an isomorphism. In this case, of course, $f_*$ and $f^*$ are equivalences, and since one is adjoint to the other, they are mutually quasi-inverse.

Comment: thanks! correct me if I'm wrong, but one final question, in an even simpler setting:  If $f$ is an isomorphism (automorphism) on $X=Y$, is it true that then for every coherent $\mathcal{F}$ on $X$ we already have an iso $\mathcal{F} \rightarrow f^*\mathcal{F}$ by pulling back sections...?